# Why I don't see LTS on the ISO filename downloaded?

Tags: release-management

I downloaded this Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a mac plus the windows version but I don't see LTS on the ISO file name. Any hint?

Answer (score 4):

That is not a problem. 14.04 is a lts release and the iso is called "   ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso" or "ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso" . There is no "LTS" in the name.

Answer (score 2):

14.04 is an [LTS (Long Term Support)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) release, it is supported for 5 years instead of 9 months:

[image: releases table]
<sup>from [`https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)</sup>

So 14.04 is a LTS release, it does not matter that LTS does not appear in the iso filename.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, 14.04 is an LTS. You can verify this by extracing README.diskdefines from within the ISO and opening it in a text editor.

You stated that you have Windows and OSX currently. I'm not familiar with OSX, but on Windows 8 this can be accomplished by:

1. Right clicking on the ISO and choosing open with "Windows Explorer".
2. Right click on the document and choose open with "Notepad".

If you are running an older version of Windows you won't be able to use Explorer, but you can always download 7-zip for free, and use it to extract the file.

Within the document it will say something like:

> #define DISKNAME  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" - Release amd64